# Which oxidation states were used when Pauling developed his electronegativity scale?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, periodic-trends, electronegativity

Paulings electronegativity is a relative scale, based on the difference in electronegativity between X and Y, $\Delta EN = 0.102 \sqrt {\Delta}$, where $\Delta = (X-Y)_{measured}-(X-Y)_{theoretical}$ bond energies.

But what is the oxidation state of X and Y? Is it an average of the common oxidation states for each element, or is it simply the most common oxidation state? Or do I have it all wrong to begin with?

Comment: Wikipedia Electronegativity article has a section dedicated to this issue. A single valued EN, whatever defined, it is a simplification nevertheless good in many instances. It is expected that one comes here when something isn't clear or covered by very easy to find and more or less reputed sources.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the wikipedia article only mentions that EN changes with oxidation state, and that Allred Rochow calculated some EN-values based on averages of some transition metals. I can't find anything about what oxidation state Linus Pauling himself used for his EN-values..

Comment: Basically a value for each oxidation states he deal with. But the article should satisfy your question nevertheless. There is no a periodic table electronegativity in reality. Yet, that or other derived values proved useful.